# Why is $c$ and $h$ not constant in this equation?

Tags: special-relativity, photons, speed-of-light, error-analysis, wavelength

From the equation:

$$(mc^2)^2+(cp)^2 = E^2$$

When rest mass = 0 we get $p = E/c \approx E = p\cdot c$

Looking specifically at photons (zero mass): Granted that c remains constant, any change in E should be directly proportional to change in p correct?

If we then look at the energy of a photon equation:

```
E = hc/λ
:. As the wavelength increases the energy of the photon decreases
```

Is it correct to combine the two above equations to form:

```
P*c = hc/λ
:. p = h/λ
:. h/λ = E/c {The wavelength to energy relationship is still present}
```

If we then use that last equation with the information:

```
λ = 450 nm ; 
E =  4.4*10^-19 J

(6.62607015*10^-34 Js)/(450*10^-9 m) = 1.47246*10-27
(4.4*10^-19 J)/(2.99792458*10^8 m/s) = 1.467682*10-27
```

Is this difference negligible from rounding error of Planks constant and the speed of light? The two values were found [HERE](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?c%7Csearch_for=light) and [HERE](https://physics.nist.gov/cgi-bin/cuu/Value?h). If not, considering the relationship between wavelength and energy stayed constant, would this mean that either c or h is not constant?

Comment: There are direct ways to show the relationship. No rounding is required.

Comment: Please, use laTex notation for formulae. It's about writing them in between of dollar symbols, and laTex commands inside. See here: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: The simple textbook answer to this question is the [de Broglie wavelength](https://en.wikiversity.org/wiki/De_Broglie_wavelength) which you've even included yourself as $p = h / \lambda$.

Comment: Hatmix5, I've partially edited your question to get you started using MathJax. Can you take it from here?

Answer (score 1):

You were done after the first two lines of math. There is no quantum mechanics involved in this relationship. It's purely classical. The discrepancy at the end is because you rounded excessively.

Comment: I see no classical physics there at all. It's purely relativistic (first line) and QM (rest)

Comment: @FGSUZ: In physics, "classical" means not quantum-mechanical. Special and general relativity are classical theories.

Comment: “Classical” is overloaded. Sometimes it means “pre-20th century physics” and other times “non-quantum physics”. An authoritative example of the latter comes from Landau & Lifshitz: the discussion of special relativity is in the volume *The classical theory of fields*.

Comment: @dmckee: I'm not aware of any careful, well-informed writers who use "classical" to exclude relativity.

Comment: Okay, it seems I've got another concept of relativity, but the rest is quantum anyways haha.

Answer (score 1):

You have used values that are given to up to two significant figures to calculate the same quantity twice. The results are consistent to two significant figures. I don’t see any problem here, and it certainly doesn’t imply that $c$ and $h$ are not constant.